# Why is validation taking place in jsonschema?

Tags: python, json, jsonschema

Why is the data validation successful?

```
from jsonschema import validate
schema = {
         "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
            "type": "object",
            "retMsg": {
                "type": "str",
                "const": "OK"
            },
            "result": {
                "type": "object",
                "required": ["orderId", "orderLinkId"],
                "properties": {
                    "orderId": {"type": "str"},
                    "orderLinkId": {"type": "str"}
                },
            },
            "required": [
                "retMsg",
                "result"
            ]
        }
        
raw_data = {
            "retMsg": "OK",
            "result": {
                "orderId": [],
                "orderLinkId": "abcde"
            }
        }
validate(instance=raw_data, schema=schema)
```

In theory, validation should be carried out - since the OrderID is a list and not a string as required by the scheme, however, everything is OK, there are no errors.
It may be necessary to change the link to the schema template, but I don't understand which one I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your schema is not correct, only the `"required": ["retMsg","result"]` part is used. You can confirm this by checking against data with missing or misspelled keys.

- You need to put the children definitions of an object into a `properties` key.
- And JSONSchema uses `string`, not `str`.

After fixing your schema I got:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "retMsg",
    "result"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "retMsg": {
      "type": "string",
      "const": "OK"
    },
    "result": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "orderId",
        "orderLinkId"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "orderId": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "orderLinkId": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Validation:

```
>>> validate(instance=raw_data, schema=schema)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\jsonschema\validators.py", line 1312, in validate
    raise error
jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError: [] is not of type 'string'

Failed validating 'type' in schema['properties']['result']['properties']['orderId']:
    {'type': 'string'}

On instance['result']['orderId']:
    []
```